# javascript shows output of only last iteration of for loops with promise object inside

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wrote a `node.js` script to use [jimp](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp) to get all image files from a directory, (which I take as input), run some manipulations on that and then save them in the target directory (another input) as `filename.suffix.extension`. I take suffix also as input.

**But I only see the last file from the list that I collect as to be present in the target directory.**

```
// imports
var Jimp = require('jimp');
const fs = require('fs')

// inputs
dir = process.argv[2]
target = process.argv[3]
suffix = process.argv[4]

// collect files
let dirCont = fs.readdirSync( dir );
const files = dirCont.filter( ( elm ) => /.*\.(png|jpg)/gi.test(elm) );

// run jimp on each file and write to target directory
for (file in files)
{  
    target_file = target+files[file].replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "")+'.'+suffix+files[file].match(/\.[^/.]+$/)
    Jimp.read(dir+'/'+files[file]).then(function (file) {
        return file.resize(256, 256)     // resize
             .quality(60)                 // set JPEG quality
             .greyscale()                 // set greyscale
             .write(target_file); // save
    })

}
```

I run the entire thing using grunt.

following up from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) question, things that I tried:

***but still pretty much not working***

## Immediately-Invoked Function Expression

```
var Jimp = require('jimp');
const fs = require('fs')

dir = process.argv[2]
target = process.argv[3]
suffix = process.argv[4]
let dirCont = fs.readdirSync( dir );
const files = dirCont.filter( ( elm ) => /.*\.(png|jpg)/gi.test(elm) );

for (file in files)
{
    (function(index) {
    console.log("index: "+index)
    target_file = target+files[index].replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "")+'.'+suffix+files[index].match(/\.[^/.]+$/)
    Jimp.read(dir+'/'+files[index]), function (err, filee) {
             if (err) throw err;
             filee.resize(256, 256)     // resize
             .quality(60)                 // set JPEG quality
             .greyscale()                 // set greyscale
             .write(target_file); // save
    }
    })(file);

}
```

### Result:

Still only the last file is written

## Function.prototype.bind

```
var Jimp = require('jimp');
const fs = require('fs')

dir = process.argv[2]
target = process.argv[3]
suffix = process.argv[4]
let dirCont = fs.readdirSync( dir );
const files = dirCont.filter( ( elm ) => /.*\.(png|jpg)/gi.test(elm) );
var funcs = {}
for (file in files)
{
    console.log(file)
    console.log(files[file])

    target_file = target+files[file].replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "")+'.'+suffix+files[file].match(/\.[^/.]+$/)
    funcs[file] = Jimp.read(dir+'/'+files[file]), function (err, filee) {
        return filee.resize(256, 256)     // resize
             .quality(60)                 // set JPEG quality
             .greyscale()                 // set greyscale
             .write(target_file); // save
    }.bind(this, file)

}

for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  funcs[j]();
}
```

### Result:

Error message:

```
  funcs[j]();
          ^
TypeError: funcs[j] is not a function
```

*I discovered it is a promise object*

## forEach implementation

still only the last iteration was printed

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Always declare variables!! `const target_file` ...

Comment: @JonasW. can you tell me how does that affect my case? Since I am writing to the file inside each iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `target_file`, in each of these, is a shared variable (each iteration is modifying the same one).  Just change:

```
target_file =
```

to

```
let target_file =
```

or

```
const target_file =
```

and you should be fine.

Comment: I am new to js, thanks for the quick reply. I thought that `target_file` was a local variable and constructing and destroying with each function call

Comment: would you answer that even if the `target_file` is a shared variable, I am writing the files inside each iteration. It seems like the writing part happened after the iterations were finished

Comment: when you do `Jimp.read(dir+'/'+files[file]), function (err, filee) { /* do stuff */ })`, the `/* do stuff */` part is a callback, which implies it's going to happen asynchronously.  By the time that function runs, most likely, every iteration of the loop has completed (and then the callback gets called once for each file, but they all write to the same target_file so it seems as if only one of them was called).